# CPU/RAM upgrade for HP Proliant ML350 G5

Tags: memory, hp, central-processing-unit

I have an HP ML350 G5 server with a single Intel 5130 dual core Xeon installed. Is it possible to upgrade it to a dual processor system? I've looked at the quickspecs and spent a couple of hours searching online but haven't been able to find a conclusive answer.

Is it as simple as purchasing, for example, two Xeon E5405's and a VRM, or are there caveats I need to watch out for?

Additionally, the quickspecs shows the 5130 supporting up to 16 GB of RAM, but quad core models support up to 32 GB. The Intel ARK for the 5000Z chipset says it supports a total of 16 GB of RAM (but it doesn't specify if it is per processor or not).

Ultimately, I would like to upgrade from the existing Xeon 5130 with 4 GB of RAM to two Xeon 5405's with 32 GB of RAM. Is it possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I disagree with the accepted answer. There were two system chipsets sold with this series of server. The initial G5 servers were introduced in late 2006 with the Intel 5000Z chipsets. Those supported the Intel 5100-series CPU you have now.

**You probably won't be able to accept the CPUs and RAM you want in the system you have now.**

The HP ProLiant G5-series of server were long-lived, coming out in 2006 and hitting end-of-life in 2009. That time period saw the Intel 5000, 5100, 5200, 5300 and 5400 processors. There was a revision to the product to support quad-core CPUs with the introduction of the the 5300-series processors. That accounts for the difference in CPU support and RAM capacity you see here.

The easiest way to determine your server's capability is through the system board part number (#15 in the diagram below) and the following replacement part numbers:

- 413984-001 was the original board (*probably what you have*).
- 439399-001 was the board that came with the newer quad-core models.
- 461081-001 is the standard repair part that can support all of the CPUs in that range.

Are your optical drives IDE or are they SATA? That will conclusively tell you what you have.

[image]

[image]

---

Despite all of the above, I think it's a bad idea to invest anything into this platform. You can buy a high-end model from this line for under $300US. You should be looking at Intel Nehalem 5500 (or HP ProLiant G6) and better servers these days...

Comment: The DVD/CD-R is PATA, but luckily the board I have is the 439399-001. Good thing, too, because I already ordered a new E5405 CPU off of eBay for it (based on the previously accepted answer). I decided to just get a single 5405 (to replace the 5130) and 16 GB of RAM (instead of 32) -- the entire upgrade was only $60. I'm just using this server for virtualization labs, not production. Thanks everyone for your input, it is greatly appreciated :-)

Comment: Oh, perfect... that's a good deal and you have the right board for this. Please be sure to download and run the bootable [**HP Service Pack for ProLiant DVD**](http://h17007.www1.hp.com/us/en/enterprise/servers/products/service_pack/spp/index.aspx). It will bring all of the firmware components in line and stabilize the platform.

Comment: That's great! Thank you so much for that link. I've been doing network engineering for awhile but I'm just now getting into servers and system admin stuff, so I have a little bit of catching up to do :-)

Comment: Just an update: I received the CPU today and it wouldn't accept it right away. I performed a firmware upgrade and then it did accept it without issue. Thanks again for the help :-)